# Prevent embedding interop types in nuspec package file

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I've created a nuget package for an interop library. When using this package, Nuget automatically sets "Embed Interop Types" to "True".

However, in my project this should be "False".

Is there a way in Nuget to specify that interop types should *not* be embedded?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's quite an old question but if someone faces this then follow the below steps :

While creating a NuGet package, add a tools folder and add a file named: install.ps1

Write below PowerShell commands which define the project requirement, In my case, I had to add EmbedInteropTypes: false for SapROTWr library.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$project.Object.References | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Interop.SapROTWr" } |  ForEach-Object { $_.EmbedInteropTypes = $false }
```

Now add that package to your project and checkout the properties.